# How to solve "Variable is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I'm trying to retrain existing pretrained net from object-detection-API. It is ssd_mobilenet_v2. Pre-trained on COCO dataset. I was reproducing steps according to the tutorial pinned to obj-detection-API.

The model starts training anyway, but the % mAP is low. I'm new to CNN's at all, so any help is appreciated.

When I start training, then this warning appears and I can't find a fix.

I'm running it in a google-collaboratory notebook with this command

```
# Training
!python object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
--model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
--num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
--alsologtostderrps
```

this are the warnings I get:

```
WARNING:root:Variable [FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/weights] is     available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 512]], model variable shape: [[3, 3, 256, 512]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 128, 256]], model variable shape: [[3, 3, 128, 256]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 128, 256]], model variable shape: [[3, 3, 128, 256]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 64, 128]], model variable shape: [[3, 3, 64, 128]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
```

after running like 10 minutes it prints out this:

```
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=1.73s).
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.002
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.000
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.006
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.040
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.002
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.026
Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.050
```

I haven't changed the *.ckpt files just downloaded the original pretrained version of ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29 and used these and linked them in the .config file.

I'm trying to figure it out for more than a day. 
Thank you for help.

Comment: The warnings simply mean that the weights from the checkpoint have a different shape than the model layer you're trying to load them in to. Therefore, those layers won't be initialized from the checkpoint but will be randomly initialized instead.

Comment: well @LukeDeLuccia, that I understand, but what I don't know is, why is it so. When I use only the already pretrained model saved in the `.ckpt` files (i downloaded). Maybe someone faced same issue ?

Comment: @MiroslavKarpíšek  I am seeing the exact same problem of low AP's with pre-trained weights for maskrcnn (mask_rcnn_resnet50_atrous_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz)  

I want to also start training with pre-trained weights on the coco2017 dataset. I however dont see any warning about variables not get loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue as Miroslav (exact same 4 warning messages).  While @GPhilo is right that this warning message means that the checkpoint doesn't match the model, it appears that there was an issue generating this specific pre-trained checkpoint. Specifically, the `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz` checkpoint seems to have been generated using a pre-release version of the config file.  Here is the link to the related issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5315

In the end, I switched from the `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config` file in the tensorflow/models git repo to the `pipeline.config` file included with the pre-trained checkpoint.  Besides the normal settings that need changing, you also need to remove the `batch_norm_trainable` flag.  More info on this bug is here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4066

Note: My first attempt was to switch to the quantized version of MobileNet V2 SSD, but I didn't get the accuracy that I hoped for after re-training the model with my data set (not sure why).

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says (taking the first line, they are all similar):

> layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/weights is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. **Checkpoint shape: [[1, 1, 256, 512]], model variable shape: [[3, 3, 256, 512]]**.

The shape in the checkpoint, as interpreted per [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805860/tensorflow-understanding-tensor-shapes-for-convolution), is that of a **1x1** convolution (the 1,1 at the beginning of the shape).
The shape in your model is correctly the one of a 3x3 convolution.
Now, this is weird because the layer name *in the checkpoint* has "3x3", although that would be wrong, given the weights shape.

It seems, then, you're using a checkpoint that used 1x1 convolutions for the layers you're having issues with, despite those layers having a name that implies being 3x3 convolutions. What you could try as a workaround to use the checkpoint you have is to amend the model modifying the function that builds it to use 1x1 convolutions instead (although I can't say for sure where that would be).

As per having a low %mAP, that is of course due to having part of the model reinitialized and not loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem with mAP stands me clear, although I thought that 1x1 || 3x3 convolution should be at the end of the pipeline and shouldn't have so much power in the learning process (just assuming)
 
Yes, it is weird. When I run the model, it prints out this warning and then it makes checkpoints as well. When I stop it and run from the last checkpoint (I would assume that the mistake about the wrong shape must be overwritten by the new checkpoint) but the warning appears again - I would say it must be some serializing issue inside of the object detection training script.

Comment: The fact that making new checkpoints still raises the warning seems definitely very suspicious.. you said that you're working on a Colab. Would it be possible to add a link to that to the question?

Comment: After further research this looks to be a problem on their side: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3922